# Json a Xml con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, xml, atributos

Soy nuevo en javascript y requiero pasar una lista de parametros de un Objeto Json a un fragmento de xml el cual se incorporara después en un xml mas grande, trabajo este requerimiento con la web de apigee y logro convertir el objeto json en un xml con una política que ofrece apigee sin embargo no logro agregar los namespaces y unos atributos de la forma como lo espera el servicio al cual le voy a apuntar.

en este momento al utilizar la politica de apigee obtengo esta salida:

```
      <listaParametros>
                        <valParametro id = "empresa">
                            <valor>BANCO  S.A.</valor>
                            <id>empresa</id>
                        </valParametro>
                        <valParametro>
                            <valor>Eduardo Enrique Mendoza Lozano</valor>
                            <id>nombres_apellidos</id>
                        </valParametro>
                        <valParametro>
                            <valor>3,723,870</valor>
                            <id>Cliente_numeroIdentificacion</id>
                        </valParametro>
                        <valParametro>
                            <valor>término indefinido</valor>
                            <id>tipo_contrato</id>
                        </valParametro>
                        <valParametro>
                            <valor>01 de Diciembre de 1983</valor>
                            <id>fecha_ingreso_compania</id>
                        </valParametro>
                        <valParametro>
                            <valor>Asesor Apoyo (C.P) 0203</valor>
                            <id>cargo_actual</id>
                        </valParametro>
                        <valParametro>
                            <valor>25 días del mes de Enero de 2022</valor>
                            <id>fecha_actual</id>
                        </valParametro>
                        <valParametro>
                            <valor>3300000 ext 50360</valor>
                            <id>mesa_ayuda</id>
                        </valParametro>
                        <valParametro>
                            <valor>JUAN ERNESTO GALINDO CORDOBA</valor>
                            <id>nombre_funcionario</id>
                        </valParametro>
                        <valParametro>
                            <valor>f9524407.jpg</valor>
                            <id>nombre_imagen_firma_funcionario</id>
                        </valParametro>
                        <valParametro>
                            <valor>Director De Gestion Servicios De Talento Humano</valor>
                            <id>cargo_funcionario</id>
                        </valParametro>
                </listaParametros>
```

Y la que requiero es similar a esta:

```
<tns:listaParametros>
                <tns:valParametro id=\"empresa\">
                    <tns:valor>FIDUCIARIA  SA</tns:valor>
                </tns:valParametro>
                <tns:valParametro id=\"nombres_apellidos\">
                    <tns:valor>Diana Milena Sanchez Mujica</tns:valor>
                </tns:valParametro>
                <tns:valParametro id=\"Cliente_numeroIdentificacion\">
                    <tns:valor>1,018,43</tns:valor>
                </tns:valParametro>
                <tns:valParametro id=\"tipo_contrato\">
                    <tns:valor>t&#233;rmino indefinido</tns:valor>
                </tns:valParametro>
                <tns:valParametro id=\"fecha_ingreso_compania\">
                    <tns:valor>08 de Septiembre de 2015</tns:valor>
                </tns:valParametro>
                <tns:valParametro id=\"cargo_actual\">
                    <tns:valor>Coordinador (C.T) 9300</tns:valor>
                </tns:valParametro>
                <tns:valParametro id=\"fecha_actual\">
                    <tns:valor>04 d&#237;as del mes de Enero de 2022</tns:valor>
                </tns:valParametro>
                <tns:valParametro id=\"mesa_ayuda\">
                    <tns:valor>3300000 ext 50360</tns:valor>
                </tns:valParametro>
                <tns:valParametro id=\"nombre_funcionario\">
                    <tns:valor>FERNANDO HINESTROSA REY</tns:valor>
                </tns:valParametro>
                <tns:valParametro id=\"nombre_imagen_firma_funcionario\">
                    <tns:valor>f79141253.jpg</tns:valor>
                </tns:valParametro>
                <tns:valParametro id=\"cargo_funcionario\">
                    <tns:valor>Presidente Fiduciaria </tns:valor>
                </tns:valParametro>
            </tns:listaParametros>
```

Para un poco mas de contexto el json con el cual trabajo al inicio lo obtengo de esta forma:

```
var certificado = getValueField(certificados, "Data.CertificadoUno");

var parametro = {};
var listaParametros = {};
listaParametros.valParametro = [];

parametro = {};
parametro.valor = certificado.codCompania;
parametro.id = context.getVariable('propertyset.apiVariables.nombreIdEmpresa');
listaParametros.valParametro.push(parametro);

parametro = {};
parametro.valor = certificado.valNombre;
parametro.id = context.getVariable('propertyset.apiVariables.nombreIdNombreApellidos');
listaParametros.valParametro.push(parametro);

parametro = {};
parametro.valor = certificado.valNumeroIdentificacion;
parametro.id = context.getVariable('propertyset.apiVariables.nombreIdNumeroIdentificacion');
listaParametros.valParametro.push(parametro);

parametro = {};
parametro.valor = certificado.codTipoContrato;
parametro.id = context.getVariable('propertyset.apiVariables.nombreIdTipoContrato');
listaParametros.valParametro.push(parametro);

parametro = {};
parametro.valor = certificado.fecIngreso;
parametro.id = context.getVariable('propertyset.apiVariables.nombreIdFechaIngresoCompania');
listaParametros.valParametro.push(parametro);

parametro = {};
parametro.valor = certificado.valCargo;
parametro.id = context.getVariable('propertyset.apiVariables.nombreIdCargoActual');
listaParametros.valParametro.push(parametro);

if (null !== parametroValorSueldo && null !== parametroValorSueldo.id) {
    parametroValorSueldo.valor = certificado.valSueldo;
    listaParametros.valParametro.push(parametroValorSueldo);
}

if (null !== parametroCiudadExpedicion && null !== parametroCiudadExpedicion.id) {
    parametroCiudadExpedicion.valor = certificado.valCiudadExpedicion;
    listaParametros.valParametro.push(parametroCiudadExpedicion);
}

if (null !== parametroNombreSolo && null !== parametroNombreSolo.id) {
    parametroNombreSolo.valor = certificado.valNombreSolo;
    listaParametros.valParametro.push(parametroNombreSolo);
}

if (null !== parametroDependencia && null !== parametroDependencia.id) {
    parametroDependencia.valor = certificado.valNombreDependencia;
    listaParametros.valParametro.push(parametroDependencia);
}

parametro = {};
parametro.valor = certificado.fecExpedicion;
parametro.id = context.getVariable('propertyset.apiVariables.nombreIdFechaActual');
listaParametros.valParametro.push(parametro);

parametro = {};
parametro.valor = context.getVariable('propertyset.apiVariables.nombreValorMesaAyuda');
parametro.id = context.getVariable('propertyset.apiVariables.nombreIdMesaAyuda');
listaParametros.valParametro.push(parametro);

parametro = {};
parametro.valor = certificado.valNombreFirmante;
parametro.id = context.getVariable('propertyset.apiVariables.nombreIdNombreFuncionario');
listaParametros.valParametro.push(parametro);

parametro = {};
parametro.valor = certificado.valImagenFirma;
parametro.id = context.getVariable('propertyset.apiVariables.nombreIdNombreImagenFirmaFuncionario');
listaParametros.valParametro.push(parametro);

parametro = {};
parametro.valor = certificado.valCargoFirmante;
parametro.id = context.getVariable('propertyset.apiVariables.nombreIdCargoFuncionario');
listaParametros.valParametro.push(parametro);

print("lista parametros", JSON.stringify(listaParametros));
context.setVariable('listaParametrosCerUno', JSON.stringify(listaParametros));
```

con el cual obtengo una salida similar a esta.

```
{
    "valParametro": [{
            "valor": "BANCO  S.A.",
            "id": "empresa"
        }, {
            "valor": "Eduardo Enrique Mendoza Lozano",
            "id": "nombres_apellidos"
        }, {
            "valor": "3,723",
            "id": "Cliente_numeroIdentificacion"
        }, {
            "valor": "término indefinido",
            "id": "tipo_contrato"
        }, {
            "valor": "01 de Diciembre de 1983",
            "id": "fecha_ingreso_compania"
        }, {
            "valor": "Asesor Apoyo (C.P) 0203",
            "id": "cargo_actual"
        }, {
            "valor": "25 días del mes de Enero de 2022",
            "id": "fecha_actual"
        }, {
            "valor": "3300000 ext 50360",
            "id": "mesa_ayuda"
        }, {
            "valor": "JUAN ERNESTO GALINDO CORDOBA",
            "id": "nombre_funcionario"
        }, {
            "valor": "f9524407.jpg",
            "id": "nombre_imagen_firma_funcionario"
        }, {
            "valor": "Director De Gestion Servicios De Talento Humano",
            "id": "cargo_funcionario"
        }
    ]
}
```

Agradezco su ayuda, con este incoveniente de nuevo reitero no llevo mucho tiempo con javascript, tambien se que podria realizar el cambio en el xml que muestro al principio con expresiones regulares pero aun no las se utilizar muy bien.

Comment: Mírate esto a ver si te sirve: https://goessner.net/download/prj/jsonxml/... y aqui tienes más opciones: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773550/convert-xml-to-json-and-back-using-javascript

Comment: No conozco apigee, pero una búsqueda rápida me muestra que en la configuración hay una etiqueta `<DefaultNamespaceNodeName>...</DefaultNamespaceNodeName>`. Quizá sea lo que estás buscando (https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/reference/policies/json-xml-policy#namespace)